# Сколько занимает полная переиндексация системы у Spotlight?

Tags: macos

После обновления до Big Sur заметил странную работу системы, например:

- в Alfred перестали искаться некоторые приложения
- При выборе тэга в Finder файлы с этим тэгом отображаются через секунд 30
- Тэг удаляется спустя полминуты или позже
- В Почте переключение между смарт-папками тоже занимает до минуты, то есть отрыл одну папку переключился на другую, а в ней отображаются письма из предыдущей, а спустя n-ое время уже письма из текущей папки.

Сбросил NVRAM и SCM, потом запустил полную переиндексацию Спотлайта, но она уже сутки вот в таким состоянии, полоска индекса вообще не двигается:

[image: Спотлайт]

Это нормально?
При этом `fs_usage mdworker mds` показывает, что сервис что-то там на диске делает и не завис.
Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, как решили проблему?

Comment: А какое железо?

Comment: MacBook Pro 17 года, диск 512 гб